# What happens to an object reference after it is set to null

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

I know an object reference or object handle has a size itself and the size is JVM dependent. I am just wondering what will happen after it has been explicitly set to null. Say we have a variable `Object o = new Object()` and later we set `o = null`. Will it be garbage collected?

Comment: The reference is cleaned up if it's out of scope, same as the heap it points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example:

```
Object o = new Object()
o = null;
```

Assume `o` is either a field or a local variable/parameter. In the former situation it occupies 4/8 bytes in some other (outer) object. These bytes will be garbage collected when outer object is garbage collected.

If `o` is a parameter/local variable, no garbage collection is needed, the JVM will "recycle" the stack and simply reuse/erase that space.

Comment: So, the name "o" is free after GC? Is it possible to assign some other value to it? And what about the type? Previously it was "object", should it have to be "object" later as well or may be "int" for example?

Answer (score 1):

References aren't objects and they are not subject to GC, other than in objects that contain them. They live in lexical scopes and they have the same lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

No object will be garbage-collected while any kind of reference to it exists.  If all the references that point to an object are set to null or are made to point to other objects, then the object may be garbage-collected, but it will no longer be "the object to which those references refer".

Note that Java has a class called `WeakReference`, which is designed to hold a reference to an object without preventing it from being garbage-collected.  If when the system performs a garbage-collection there exists any object which is the target of a `WeakReference`, but would *otherwise* be eligible for garbage-collection, the system will invalidate the `WeakReference`.  At that point, if nobody asked the `WeakReference` for its target before it was invalidated, there will no longer be any reference to the object, and it will thus be eligible for collection.

Comment: You asked what happens to a reference when the target object is garbage-collected.  For a normal reference that will simply *never happen*, so the "title" question would be meaningless.  For a `WeakReference`, the answer answer is that the `WeakReference` is invalidated *before* its target is garbage-collected.

Comment: @dragon66: Once you set the reference to null, it will no longer have anything to do with the object in question, and will neither know nor care what happens to it.  Likewise if a reference which used to point to `object1` is changed to point to `object2`, it will no longer know nor care what happens to `object1`.  Why would you expect a reference to affect, or affected by, what might happen to an object which is not its target?